# verifiying ubuntu iso with repository gpg-keys

Tags: security, repository, iso

I want to verify that a downloaded ISO is not being poisoned by the NSA or any other immoral agent. To do this I would very much use a signing-checking way.

I am aware of [VerifyIsoHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto). Still I am not very happy with offered. If some agent can manipulate one file download he surely can manipulate all file downloads. So the public key I get from a key-server can just be cheated to make the manipulated ISO file check okay, while indeed it has been injected a rootkit or worse.

Now I am aware of that there is unfortunatelly no 100% sure way. But starting with the assumption that my current system is safe I have those keys used in the [SecureApt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt) mechanism.

My Question therefore:

**How can the keys that I already trust in SecureApt (= the ordinary Ubuntu repository keys) be used to verify a freshly downloaded ISO?**

Indeed it would serve me well also if I could via the Ubuntu Repo (and hence in a deb that is verified implicitly via SecureApt) get those public keys which would be necessary to verify the signature of the iso.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: of course I am aware that if Canonical is immoral and colaborates with NSA (which has money hey) we are all poisend anyhow. Let's just assume something like this could never happen, ok?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following steps allow you to verify the SHA256SUMS file for the downloaded Ubuntu iso:

1. Open Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Import the keys from /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg via `gpg --import /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg`. You should see something like this:

   ```
   gpg: keyring `/root/.gnupg/secring.gpg' created
   gpg: key 437D05B5: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key " imported
   gpg: key FBB75451: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key " imported
   gpg: Total number processed: 2
   gpg:               imported: 2
   gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
   ```

   The line

   ```
   gpg: key FBB75451: public key "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key " imported
   ```

   shows you that you imported the GPG key for signing CD images (iso files) is the one with the following fingerprint:

   ```
   Primary key fingerprint: C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632  CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451
   ```

   and hence the ID `FBB7 5451`
3. Having imported the key you can then download the files SHA256SUMS, MD5SUMS, SHA1SUMS and their respective signatures *SHA256SUMS.gpg, MD5SUMS.gpg
4. Now you can use this command `gpg --verify SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS` to check if the file SHA256SUMS is legitimate. If so then you should see something like this:

   ```
   gpg: Signature made Thu 14 Feb 2013 06:38:41 PM CET using DSA key ID FBB75451
   gpg: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key "
   gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
   gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
   Primary key fingerprint: C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632  CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451
   ```

   If the SHA256SUMS file has been altered then something like this will appear instead:

   ```
   gpg: Signature made Thu 14 Feb 2013 06:38:41 PM CET using DSA key ID FBB75451
   gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key "
   ```

Basically, instead of following step 2 in the [howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto) referred to in the question and getting the key from the keyserver, which may have been compromised, you use the key provided with your existing Ubuntu installation that you trust.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work nicely:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-keyring
gpgv --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg SHA256SUMS.gpg SHA256SUMS
grep ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso SHA256SUMS | sha256sum --check
```