# Is there any way to verify a Ubuntu iso or hashsum via HTTPS?

Tags: security

Neither the ISO nor the hashsum is available via HTTPS. Is there any way to verify you're not getting man-in-the-middled?

Comment: If you want any help - please make sure your question is clear and understandable. What exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: @Ashu I'm trying to install a verified ubuntu iso. Using a hashsum from the same server via `http` is almost pointless.

Comment: http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Comment: Why do you assume https is safe? :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I hope I haven't given that impression. But unlike http, I assume https is safe from your average teenager.

Answer (score 5):

The hashes and iso's are only provided via http, so md5sum-checking is insufficient. As [@Doug Smythies](https://askubuntu.com/users/372967/doug-smythies) explained in a comment on a deleted answer:

> We (the Ubuntu Doc team) no longer maintain the [https](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) page, because it is pretty much impossible to do so. The people with the ability to do an [https page won't.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website/+bug/1225442)

However, Ubuntu's gpg fingerprints are available via https [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto#Verify_signature).

## TLDR

1. [Download `MD5SUMS` and `MD5SUMS.gpg` for the relevant release.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)
2. [Verify the `MD5SUMS` with the `MD5SUMS.gpg` and **check that the fingerprint is the same as on this web page.**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto#Verify_signature)
3. [Verify the iso with the `MD5SUMS`.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#Check_the_iso_file)

Comment: Can I ask the difference http or https makes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Difference_from_HTTP

Answer (score 3):

Whilst Canonical isn't providing HTTPS some of the officially recognized 3rd-party mirrors do, so that may be a viable alternative. Even without HTTPS you can always compare the checksums provided by several different mirrors (that you recognize) to help decrease the odds of a MITM (Man In The Middle).

**List of Official 3rd-Party Mirrors CAPABLE of HTTPS:**

(remove the - from h-ttps, only put there because too many urls)

- https://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu-cd/
- https://ftp.fau.de/ubuntu-releases/
- https://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/ubuntu-releases/
- https://ftp.lysator.liu.se/ubuntu-releases/
- https://ftp.rnl.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/pub/ubuntu/releases/
- https://ftp.sjtu.edu.cn/ubuntu-cd/
- https://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/pub/Mirrors/releases.ubuntu.com/
- https://ftp.ucsb.edu/pub/mirrors/linux/ubuntu/
- https://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/ubuntu-releases/
- https://lug.mtu.edu/ubuntu-iso/
- https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/ubuntu/releases/
- https://mirror.beget.ru/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirror.cedia.org.ec/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirror.hmc.edu/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirror.imt-systems.com/ubuntu/
- https://mirror.kku.ac.th/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirror.one.com/ubuntu-cd/
- https://mirror.picosecond.org/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirrors.bloomu.edu/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirrors.koehn.com/ubuntureleases/
- https://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirror.stjschools.org/public/ubuntu-release/
- https://mirrors.tripadvisor.com/releases/
- https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirrors.xmission.com/ubuntu-cd/
- https://mirror.umd.edu/ubuntu-iso/
- https://mirror.vorboss.net/ubuntu-releases/
- https://mirror.yandex.ru/ubuntu-releases/
- https://ubuntu.koyanet.lv/releases/
- https://ubuntu.localmsp.org/ubuntu-releases/
- https://ubuntu.tuxuri.com/releases/
- https://ubuntu.uni-sofia.bg/releases/
- https://ubuntu.vxroutes.com/
- https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/releases.ubuntu.com/

In future, for those whom don't fancy checking mirrors by hand for HTTPS, you can use [Https Finder](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/606864/https-finder/), which was the tool used to find these mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

You can download your favorite ubuntu from here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

and you can see the md5 checksum from here:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Infact 2nd link contains all the .iso and the md5 checksums.

Look for this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326397/verifiying-ubuntu-iso-with-repository-gpg-keys?rq=1) for verifying the .iso file

I will suggest go for Ubuntu desktop 14.04 LTS(Long term support).

Comment: Both of those files are only provided via insecure `http`. How can I verify that they aren't both from the same man-in-the-middle?

Comment: So the only way to get the public gpg key used to sign releases is to install ubuntu?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen it didn't answer the question at the time I wrote the comment. Since then, ubfan1 added a link to a possible duplicate which Ashu adopted in his answer.

Comment: @RyneEverett - no, the public gpg keys are available on key servers. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Authentication_Tab . You should be able to identify and download the ubuntu gpg keys if you know how to use gpg, if not, well that is a separate question.

Comment: @RyneEverett. If you are downloading .iso from Windows(which most of the folks might be doing)-there is a utility in Windows 10(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533). Having said that you don't have to install ubuntu to verify md5 checksum

Comment: @Ashu - http://askubuntu.com/questions/326397/verifiying-ubuntu-iso-with-repository-gpg-keys?rq=1

Comment: Or purchase a CD / DVD from Canonical - http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17 . Works for Windows users too ;p

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It isn't clear to me that ordering a cd/dvd is a way of *verifying an iso*.

Comment: Sure, the DVD contains the has sum for the iso on it so by ordering a DVD you get the hash sum directly from canonical. I trust you know how to verify from there.