# How do I get WebEx working on Ubuntu 18.04 in 2019?

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, cisco, webex

I've spent a couple of hours trying out every single method available on askubuntu, but none of them seems to be working anymore.

The closest I've found is this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/893216) that says that "WebEx through Chrome on Ubuntu works fine for me with screen sharing", which is definitely not the case for me.

I need to be able to create personal rooms using my corporate account. However, when I try to do so, the site gives me back a *java web start* servlet. Chrome doesn't seem to be even trying to use the extension that I installed for this purpose and it definitely cannot use java since it deprecated the NPAPI plugin interface... the most I've been able to achieve was opening that servlet on firefox but screen sharing isn't working at all.

Is it actually possible for webex to work on ubuntu 18 nowadays?

Comment: BTW, I would've asked by commenting on the answer I linked, but I don't have enough reputation to do so ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: so you're using google chrome, not chromium and it's still not working? what about with ubuntu 18.10?  also have you run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxuprising/java -y && sudo apt update && sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre -y` ?

Comment: No dice. I cannot upgrade ubuntu since this is my work office PC. Installing the openjdk isn't an issue, but I cannot figure out how to open the CiscoWebExServlet file with it... I tried using the "open with" dialog box but it doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.

Comment: if `java --version` successfully returns the version you can simply pipe the file you want to run with java to it like so `java path/to/my/CiscoWebExServlet` if not but you know where the java runtime binary is you can use the it's path in the same way `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11-jre/bin/java path/to/my/CiscoWebExServlet`

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work either. It seems the file doesn't have a java main class so it can't be launched like this.