# Cisco Webex Meetings in Ubuntu Firefox

Tags: 18.04, firefox, cisco, webex

Will I be able to run Web Meetings as a web app in Firefox? I have been using Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternatively try the webex client https://askubuntu.com/questions/893215/how-do-i-get-webex-working-with-audio-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install [Cisco Webex Firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cisco-webex-extension/) in Firefox and use web app.

Comment: Do I need anything else? It couldn't open the downloaded file from Webex!

Comment: You should be open webex online link. File will not work.

Comment: This does not support everything such as sharing media files

Comment: even after installing the Cisco Webex Firefox plugin it does not work... Webex won't work with Ubuntu :-\

i.e. going to Webex.com and trying to sign in won't work... dead link