# Installing cisco webex software for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, webex

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 now and I need to install cisco webex for important meetings but I'm unable to do it. So I would be super great and good if anyone in this community helps me out with this.
I tried every method provided( only a few available in the internet), So please guys do help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get WebEx working with audio on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893215/how-do-i-get-webex-working-with-audio-on-ubuntu) then use [my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271158) from it.